# How to load saved h5 file from google colab and use it in PC

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have trained a model using pre-trained CNN and saved it in h5 format on Colab. For my project, I will need to capture images from four cameras and used the trained model to do image classification. Colab seems not able to connect to four cameras and I am thinking to do it with my pc. however, how should I use the h5.file which is located on Colab? I am new in programming and machine learning. sorry if I asked a stupid question ...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case the question is about downloading the model from [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=p2E4EKhCWEC5), it is as easy as right clicking and selecting download from file browser pane in the extreme left side.

If the question is intended on getting prediction from a model. A common template is as below

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model=load_model("model.h5")
prediction=model.predict(your_input)
best_pred=np.argmax(prediction)
```

You can also directly save the model to your google drive by [mounting](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=p2E4EKhCWEC5) the drive.